# How to change uipagecontrol's number of pages animated?

Tags: ios, animation, uipagecontrol

Is it possible to animate the change of number of pages for UIPageControl animated?
I'd like to get an animation in which the dots go to the middle an then expand with a new number of pages. Think that could look quite well.
But any other animation would be appreciated, too.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you have to build your own Page Control.
What you could do with the UIPageControl is to add a new one with the same frame and alpha = 0.0 and fade out the old page control and fade in the new with the update number of pages.

Comment: Thats what I thought I could do next when the other animation doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

Here Bellow is Some Great and useful Demo of stylist UIPageViewcontroller and it's Animation. hope this is useful to you:

http://code4app.net/ios/Styled-PageControl/4f87d11c06f6e76c32000000

http://code4app.net/ios/Page-Scrubber-Bar/50f76fb16803fa1b4a000000

http://code4app.net/ios/SMPageControl/507e30146803fa2705000000

http://code4app.net/ios/Customized-PageControl/4f67fd596803fad343000001

**SnapShot**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Very useful advice, but you actually can't animate these page controls, or did I miss something?